# Start service on another machine without credentials

Tags: powershell

I've spent the better part of yesterday and this morning looking into this. I've come across Powershell, psexec, and WMI in my research. Nothing seems to work without having credentials of the second computer.

All I want to do is simply stop a service, and then start a service on another machine in the domain where I work. Without credentials, I keep getting "Access Denied" errors.

Does anyone know if this is possible without credentials? I'd prefer a Powershell suggestion, but I'll gladly listen to all suggestions.

Comment: Why would you expect or want this to be possible? I mean you turn any service off on anyones machine anywhere. Sort of like the bad old days on windows...

Comment: if you don't have access to the machine why would it allow to stop the service?

Comment: Is PowerShell running as a local or a domain user?  Are you a domain administrator?

Comment: Tony Hopkinson, the explanation is complicated. But in short, I need to automate a deployment process, and part of it requires turning on / off services on a cluster of nodes in the domain. A powershell script sounds right for this, if possible without credentials. Rerun, the company would like to see if we can do this without including the Service Account's credentials. BACON, I'm scripting and testing as a domain user. The script would continue to be run this way, off the senior developers machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing and performing operations on Windows services on remote computers within a domain can be done easily using the [`Get-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849804.aspx), [`Stop-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849790.aspx), and [`Start-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849825.aspx) cmdlets...

```
$remoteService = Get-Service -ComputerName $remoteHost -Name $serviceName;
Stop-Service -InputObject $remoteService;
# Perform additional processing...
Start-Service -InputObject $remoteService;
```

...however you need to be an administrator on `$remoteHost`.  The `*-Service` cmdlets provide no parameters to specify alternate credentials, so it connects as the user running `powershell.exe`.  Even if you could connect as a non-administrator user you'd still need to be an administrator to stop and start services.